# Travis build failing after a cabal check warning

Tags: haskell, travis-ci, cabal, haskell-stack

Several builds, like [this one](https://travis-ci.org/capitanbatata/hierarchy/jobs/350766350), fail when executing `cabal check`:

```
++cabal check
These warnings may cause trouble when distributing the package:
* 'ghc-options: -O2' is rarely needed. Check that it is giving a real benefit
and not just imposing longer compile times on your users.
```

However, most of the other [builds in the matrix](https://travis-ci.org/capitanbatata/hierarchy/builds/350766349) do not fail after this check.

I'm using the [complex Travis configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stack/stable/doc/travis-complex.yml) suggested at the [`stack` docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/travis_ci/), and [this](https://github.com/capitanbatata/hierarchy/blob/master/.travis.yml) is the Travis configuration specific for the project I'm trying to get on CI.

Any ideas on what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of build in your travis config:

- Stack based build
- Cabal based build

If you follow the [script code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stack/stable/doc/travis-complex.yml), you will see that only `Cabal` based build has the command `cabal check` in it. That will explain why all of your Stack based builds are working fine. Now, let's see the cabal check command line in detail:

```
cabal check || [ "$CABALVER" == "1.16" ]
```

So, if your installed cabal version is 1.16, it will ignore the output of cabal check and that command is treated as a success. And infact, that's what is happening. Only one Cabal based build job is success in your travis, because it's version is `1.16`.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that the stack build was succeeding, but I didn't know why there was a cabal based build that succeeded. I wonder what can I do to avoid getting a warning because of the O2 flag. What if a package needs it.

Comment: Remove O2 option from here is an option: https://github.com/capitanbatata/hierarchy/blob/5ec3dcce8b479337264f3fd2730c78a6056f6a0e/hierarchy.cabal#L20

Comment: Yeah, but what if a package actually needs the O2 option :)